# Scientific Notation in C#

Tags: c#, scientific-notation

How do I assign a number that is in scientific notation to a variable in C#?

I'm looking to use Plancks Constant which is 6.626 X 10<sup>-34</sup>

This is the code I have which isn't correct:

```
 Decimal PlancksConstant = 6.626 * 10e-34;
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `Decimal` instead of IEEE-754?

Comment: Use decimal for financial quantities; use double for physical quantities.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should be able to declare `PlancksConstant` as a `double` and multiply 6.626 by 10e-34 like:

```
double PlancksConstant = 6.626e-34
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/kfuBtU)

Answer (score 15):

You *can* set it like this (note the `M` suffix for the `decimal` type):

```
decimal PlancksConstant = 6.626E-34M;
```

But this will **effectively be 0** because you can't represent a number with magnitude less than 1E-28 as a `decimal`.

So you need to use `double` instead and can just define this:

```
double PlancksConstant = 6.626E-34;
```